# PHP - how precisely should I define version

Tags: php, docker

I'm configuring Docker Compose file and I need to specify a PHP version.  Lets assume I just define `php:7-fpm`. Can I be sure that PHP version 7.1 will not become incompatible?

Of the following choices, what is the best way to define the version, and why?

```
php 7
php 7.0
php 7.0.9
```

Comment: PHP 7.0 is probably the way to go. PHP 7 covers too much and PHP 7.0.9 is too restrictive (since minor revisions don't generally break backwards compatibility within the same major revision)

Comment: @apokryfos - as a matter of interest, that specific version (ie PHP 7.0.9) *did* introduce a BC break that has caused [some ramifications](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11360). The PHP developers [are apparently going to revert it for 7.0.10](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72698), although it will be reintroduced for 7.1.

Comment: @Simba that wasn't on purpose though. It generally shouldn't happen.

Comment: @apokryfos - quite so, that's why they're reverting it. But it does show why sometimes you might need to specify a patch version number. Another case could be where your code relies on the fact that a known bug has been fixed, so you have to specify a minimum patch number for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of big software projects use [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). So for example, in the version number of `X.Y.Z`, the `X` is the "major" version, the `Y` is the "minor" version, and the `Z` is the "patch" version. Software following the semver specification increments:

> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

**PHP however does not follow the semver specification!**

Loads of big PHP projects use it, but the language itself does not. In the case of the PHP language itself, there can be (and are) breaking changes in the "minor" version number, not only the "major" version number. Usually, we're interested in bugfixes, and possibly other backwards-compatible changes. But we're almost definitely not interested in changes which will break our software and turn you into a firefighter.

I'm telling you about the semver specification, because for *most* projects out in the universe, you will want to declare your version to use the major version, and then accept newer minor and patch versions, like `redis:3` for example (actually Redis is a kind of bad example, because it doesn't *exactly* use semver, but close). But here specifically with PHP, you need to be more specific since you're looking for non-breaking changes only.

Therefore, `php:7.0-fpm` is probably what you're looking for.